# Resolve Http Request on Angular2 before executing code

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I've encountered problems trying to resolve an http.post request before doing some other code.

Here's the place:

```
  getRefresh(token){
    debugger;
    console.log("sono dentro get refresh");
    console.log(token);
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('grant_type','refresh_token');
    params.append('refresh_token',token);
    params.append('client_id','web_app');

    let headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8','Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa("web_app:")});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    this._http.post('http://localhost:9997/oauth/token',params.toString(),options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.saveToken(data),
        err => alert('Invalid Credentials')
      );
  }
```

Following the control flow via Browser Console, I've noticed that saveToken method is not executed asap.

The fact is that I need that method for registering some cookies, reused here:

```
if (!Cookie.get("access_token")) { 
      this.getRefresh(Cookie.get("refresh_token"));
      cookie = Cookie.get("access_token");

    } else {

      cookie = Cookie.get("access_token");
    }

      var headers = new Headers({
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  cookie                                 
      });

      var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

      return this._http.get(resourceUrl, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.text())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error().json().error || 'Server error'));
```

How can I resolve the async problem of observable?

Comment: You can't. `subscribe` calls the "success callback" when the request is done sucessfully. So, you seond code must called after `saveToken`

Comment: As you can see the getRefresh method call is before the assignment.
I've edited with complete second code.

variable cookie will be null, but the saveToken method should set 2 cookies as you can se below:
  saveToken(token){
   [...]
    Cookie.set("access_token", token.access_token, expireDate);
    Cookie.set("refresh_token", token.refresh_token, 1);
  }

Comment: `getRefresh` is called before. But it returns before the `subscribe` handler is called because it's asynchronous.

Comment: It's a big problem because i don't know how to handle async with observables, and i can't use Promises!!!

Comment: One solution, is to make `getRefresh` returning an `Observable` (or a `Promise`). Then in the caller, instead of continuing the code, you subscrbe to the return of `getRefresh` with a handler containing the code depending on the token.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getRefresh(token)` method to return the observable and use that in your calling code:

```
function getRefresh(token) {
    debugger;
    console.log("sono dentro get refresh");
    console.log(token);
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
    params.append('refresh_token', token);
    params.append('client_id', 'web_app');

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("web_app:") });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post('http://localhost:9997/oauth/token', params.toString(), options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .flatMap(
            data => this.saveToken(data),
            err => alert('Invalid Credentials')
        );
}

function getResource() {
    var cookie = Cookie.get("access_token");
    var headers = new Headers({
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cookie
    });

    var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.get(resourceUrl, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.text())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error().json().error || 'Server error'));
}

function callingCodeFunction() {
    if (!Cookie.get("access_token")) {
        this.getRefresh(Cookie.get("refresh_token"))
            .flatMap((result) => {
                getResource();
            });
    } else {
        getResource()
    }
}
```

*I've not run this code - so there may be errors, but it should serve to demonstrate the principle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now the code is giving me an error about the return of getRefresh. 
Infact, if you use the subiscribe you can't return an observable, but a subscriber

Comment: @TommasoBetti I think the updated version should be almost functional, although I havent run it. Please upvote or mark this as your answer if you found this useful.

Comment: this.getRefresh(Cookie.get("refresh_token"))
            .flatMap((result) => {
                getResource();
Is giving me an error. Problems with the types